# Autosave info from label and switch in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, save, load

I'm relatively new to developing iDevice apps. After a wide search on the Internet I eventually ended up with a question that had no answer.

I'm developing an "note-app", where users can type in info in a text field, turn on a switch and then have the opportunity to completely exit app, re-open, and the info still being there. Without a "save"-button that is. Is this possible? And maybe have a "reset"-button to discard all the info.

I'm currently using Xcode 4.5. Is there any clever xcoders out there who can give me hint?

All help will be deeply appreciated!

*EDIT*

I went with the save/load-functions and something weird happened. What happens is that when I type in something in every textfield (I have twelve), hit save, and exit the app. When I reopen the app and hit Load the text from textfield 12 loads in textfield 1. And all the other text are gone. Anyone have a clue?

Here's the code, for those who have time.

**SecondViewController.h**

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField2;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField3;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField4;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField5;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField6;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField7;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField8;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField9;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField10;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField11;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField12;
    
    IBOutlet UILabel *loaded; }

-(IBAction)save:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)load:(id)sender;
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
@implementation SecondViewController

-(IBAction)save:(id)sender{
    
    //First Save String
    NSString *savestring =myTextField.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:savestring forKey:@"saveString"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    
    //Second Save String
    NSString *savestring2 =myTextField2.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults2 setObject:savestring2 forKey:@"saveString2"];
    [defaults2 synchronize];
    
    //Third Save String
    NSString *savestring3 =myTextField3.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults3 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults3 setObject:savestring3 forKey:@"saveString3"];
    [defaults3 synchronize];
    
    //Fourth Save String
    NSString *savestring4 =myTextField4.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults4 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults4 setObject:savestring4 forKey:@"saveString4"];
    [defaults4 synchronize];
    
    //Fifth Save String
    NSString *savestring5 =myTextField5.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults5 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults5 setObject:savestring5 forKey:@"saveString5"];
    [defaults5 synchronize];
    
    //Sixth Save String
    NSString *savestring6 =myTextField6.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults6 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults6 setObject:savestring6 forKey:@"saveString6"];
    [defaults6 synchronize];
    
    //Seventh Save String
    NSString *savestring7 =myTextField7.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults7 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults7 setObject:savestring7 forKey:@"saveString7"];
    [defaults7 synchronize];
    
    //Eight Save String
    NSString *savestring8 =myTextField8.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults8 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults8 setObject:savestring8 forKey:@"saveString8"];
    [defaults8 synchronize];
    
    //Ninth Save String
    NSString *savestring9 =myTextField9.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults9 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults9 setObject:savestring9 forKey:@"saveString9"];
    [defaults9 synchronize];
    
    //Tenth Save String
    NSString *savestring10 =myTextField10.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults10 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults10 setObject:savestring10 forKey:@"saveString10"];
    [defaults10 synchronize];
    
    //Eleventh Save String
    NSString *savestring11 =myTextField11.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults11 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults11 setObject:savestring11 forKey:@"saveString11"];
    [defaults11 synchronize];
    
    //Twelvth Save String
    NSString *savestring12 =myTextField12.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults12 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults12 setObject:savestring12 forKey:@"saveString12"];
    [defaults12 synchronize];
    
    loaded.text = @"Dine notater ble lagret!"; }
-(IBAction)load:(id)sender;{
    
    //First Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring = [defaults objectForKey:@"saveString"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];
    
    //Second Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring2 = [defaults2 objectForKey:@"saveString2"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring2];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];
    
    //Third Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults3 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring3 = [defaults3 objectForKey:@"saveString3"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring3];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];
    
    //Forth Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults4 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring4 = [defaults4 objectForKey:@"saveString4"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring4];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];
    
    //Fifth Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults5 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring5 = [defaults5 objectForKey:@"saveString5"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring5];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];
    
    //Sixth Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults6 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring6 = [defaults6 objectForKey:@"saveString6"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring6];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];
    
    //Seventh Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults7 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring7 = [defaults7 objectForKey:@"saveString7"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring7];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];
    
    //Eight Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults8 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring8 = [defaults8 objectForKey:@"saveString8"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring8];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];
    
    //Ninth Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults9 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring9 = [defaults9 objectForKey:@"saveString9"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring9];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];
    
    //Tenth Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults10 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring10 = [defaults10 objectForKey:@"saveString10"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring10];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];
    
    //Eleventh Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults11 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring11 = [defaults11 objectForKey:@"saveString11"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring11];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];
    
    //Twelvth Load String
    NSUserDefaults *defaults12 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring12 = [defaults12 objectForKey:@"saveString12"];
    [myTextField setText:loadstring12];
    [loaded setText:@"Dine notater ble lastet inn!"];

}
```

For those who are *not* norwegian! "Dine notater ble lastet inn!" and "Dine notater ble lagret!" means saved and loaded.

Again, if anyone has time to look through these I would be so grateful!

Answer (score 1):

You need a class that implements the [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) protocol and set it as the value of the text field's delegate property. In the delegate, you want to implement the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method and in that method, you write the value of the text field to disk. By "disk" I mean some persistent storage, such as a `.plist` file or SQLite database or even just a text file. In your app delegate's `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:` method, you want to check if this file is present, and if it is, read it to determine how to pre-populate the text field.

This is a pretty simplistic answer but that is the gist of it without writing this entire feature for you. You can build on this as you gain more knowledge (e.g., implementing `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` and using a timer to save the user's progress even if they do not exit the text field, etc).

Comment: Ok, I just realised that I'm really bad at this. Didn't understand anything. Better get back to school!